# Can I attach a new IAM role to a running instance or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

In some case, people might have started an EC2 instance without giving a proper role and want to give it a role so that the instance would have some new privilege.

From the AWS doc [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/new-attach-an-aws-iam-role-to-an-existing-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-the-aws-cli/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=rolesforrunninginstances&sc_publisher=tw&sc_medium=social&sc_content=read-post&sc_country=global&sc_geo=global&sc_category=ec2&sc_outcome=launch), it describes the way to attach a new IAM role to a what it calls "**existing**" instance, I wonder if the "**existing**" instance actually means a "**running**" instance? or there is a difference in AWS on "**existing**" and "**running**"?

or shall I **stop** the instance in order to add a new role and **restart** it after the new role is attached?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the IAM Role that is attached to a Running instance.

There is no need to Stop the instance.

Also, you can edit an IAM Role anytime. If it is attached to an instance, the instance would immediately gain/lose the appropriate permissions.